# How to only run subquery if query has rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, subquery

I'm running an update query in mysql like this one. It is designed to update the mycount and mysum columns of record 5 in mytable *if and only if* mycount is null.

If it's not null, there are no rows to update, but the subquery still gets run, which is expensive. Is there any way to create a query that will only run the subquery if there is anything to update?

```
UPDATE mytable
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) thiscount, SUM(mycolumn) thissum
  FROM(
    SELECT mycount, mysum
    FROM <some complicated query>
  )t
)t2
SET mycount=thiscount,
    mysum=thissum
WHERE id=5;
  AND mycount IS NULL;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE id=5 and mycount IS NULL` prior to the update, thus verifying the row should be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version should only run the subquery if there are rows.  But, it has the downside of running it twice for each row being updated:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET mycount = (SELECT COUNT(*) as thiscount
                   FROM (SELECT mycount, mysum
                         FROM <some complicated query>
                        ) t
                  ),
        mysum = (SELECT SUM(mycolumn) as thissum
                 FROM (SELECT mycount, mysum
                       FROM <some complicated query>
                      ) t
                 )
    WHERE id = 5 AND mycount IS NULL;
```

You can do this so long as the subqueries do not contain `mytable`.

EDIT:

I'm not sure that the following is guaranteed to work, but it might work in practice:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET mycount = (SELECT (CASE WHEN @x := SUM(mycolumn) THEN COUNT(*)
                                ELSE COUNT(*)
                           END) as thiscount
                   FROM (SELECT mycount, mysum
                         FROM <some complicated query>
                        ) t
                  ),
        mysum = @x
    WHERE id = 5 AND mycount IS NULL;
```

I just don't think that MySQL guarantees the order of evaluation of `set` clauses.  But it would normally do them as written.

Comment: This solution does work, but as you said, requires running the same expensive subquery twice. Is there no way around that?